# Show that $\alpha$ is path homotopic to an injective $\beta:I\to S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $\alpha:I\to S^2$ be a path. Suppose $\alpha$ is not surjective and $\alpha(0)\neq\alpha(1)$. Show that $\alpha$ is path homotopic to an injective $\beta:I\to S^2$

my idea is to note that $S^2\setminus\{x_0\}$ is homotopic to a plane where $x_0$ is a point in $S^2$ and is not in the image of $\alpha$. I stop at this point.

Comment: Can't we just set $\gamma(s,t) = s\beta(t) + (1-s)\alpha(t)$ after identifying $S^2 \setminus \{x_0\}$ with the plane?

Comment: For the choice of $\beta$, even if endpoints need to be fixed, it seems we can take $\beta(t) = t\alpha(1) + (1-t)\alpha(0)$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins so, we just need to explicitly write down $\gamma$. Thank you